# How to detect effectively if the values of widgets inside an Activity changed?

Tags: android, android-widget

I have an activity with multiple sorts of controls: EditTexts, Comboboxes, Spinners. The user can modify the values of the controls accordingly. 
When the Back button was hit, I want to check if any of the values have been changed. Obviously I could add all sorts of Listeners to each widget, but I wonder: is there a more effective way to check if *any* of the widgets was used and its value modified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually added listeners to the widgets.
I feel embarrased that this is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Store initial values in an array and when you need to check if anything was modified, create a new array to store current values and compare them using [Arrays.equals](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d,%20java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29).

Of course you need to take into account things like your app process being killed and restored.

Comment: Interesting solution. I'd rather take an approach from the UI first (for example, the usage of the widget), and the data perspective is my second choice. I appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: I wonder: noone has ever tried to implement such a thing? I see many posts about suggesting custom solutions - like Android lacks of usable solutions. Shocking...